# check if string is property in xml

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to learn about SimpleXMLElement (not DOM) and this is my first time dealing with XML and PHP. I want to check if `string == node[attribute]`; then, if `another string == node/child[attribute]`; and finally, if `last string == node/child/grandchild[attribute='att']`.

Using the words in the my xml file, the pseudo code would be:

```
if dish[name] == "Potato":
  if how[name] == "fried":
    if price[size=small] == "1.23":
      do something.
```

XML file:

```
<menu>
  <dish name="Potato">
    <how name="fried">
      <price size="small">1.23</price>
      <price size="big">4.56</price>
    </how>
    <how name="baked">
      <price size="small">5.23</price>
      <price size="big">6.56</price>
    </how>
  </dish>
</menu>
```

PHP

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('xmlfile.xml');


if ( (string) $xml->dish['name'] == "Potato" ) {
  if ( (string) $xml->dish->how['name'] == 'fried' ) {
    if ( (string) $xml->dish->how['name="fried"']->price['size="small"'] == '1.23' ) {
      echo 'OK';      
    }
  } 
} else { 
    echo 'something is wrong';
}
```

The only thing that works is that I can check if 'Potato' is a dish["name"]. Everything else is wrong and I cannot figure out how to do it.

Thanks,

Comment: `how` is an array, you need to iterate over it.

Comment: To bad you don't want to use DOM: https://eval.in/145696

Comment: Thanks, @Barmar. I do not know how to iterate over the 'how' (I tried the foreach). Nothing happens. And ThW, it is not that I don't want to use DOM. It is that I am starting to learn and I was told that DOM is more complex than simpleXML. I thought it would be easier for me, a beginner, to start with simpleXML. Do you think it is not true? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select the price of small fried potatoes, you could use `xpath`, which is like SQL for XML:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x

$price = $xml->xpath("/menu/dish[@name = 'Potato']/how[@name = 'fried']/price[@size = 'small']")[0];
```

Now, if there are small fried potatoes, `$price = 1.23`, else `NULL`.

```
if (! is_null($price)) 
    echo "you can get it for $price!";
else
    echo "it is not available, sorry!";
```

Note that *array dereferencing* at the end of the `xpath`-line `...[0];`requires `PHP >= 5.4`. If you are on a lower version, update or do:

```
$price = $xml->xpath("/menu/dish[@name = 'Potato']/how[@name = 'fried']/price[@size = 'small']");
$price = $price[0];
```

see it in action: https://eval.in/145721

Comment: This is perfect, @michi! I did not know that I could use a variable to store the data from the xpath. Thank you very much for your time and your help.